# Printing data from two dictionaries in one for loop in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to loop 2 lots of 'key, value' so I can print 2 lots of data on the same line.
However it seems my code prints the output I need, but it is repeating 4 times whereas I need it to only print once.
My piece of code:

```
    for key1, value1 in dict1.items():
        pct = value1 * 100.0 / s // 1
        for key2, value2 in dict2.items():
            pct2 = value2 * 20
            print(key1, ":", int(pct), "% vs", pct2, "%")
```

Output:

```
A : 55 % vs 60 %
A : 55 % vs 20 %
A : 55 % vs 0 %
A : 55 % vs 20 %
B : 25 % vs 60 %
B : 25 % vs 20 %
B : 25 % vs 0 %
B : 25 % vs 20 %
C : 0 % vs 60 %
C : 0 % vs 20 %
C : 0 % vs 0 %
C : 0 % vs 20 %
D : 17 % vs 60 %
D : 17 % vs 20 %
D : 17 % vs 0 %
D : 17 % vs 20 %
```

But the output I'm needing is:

```
A : 55 % vs 60 %
B : 25 % vs 20 %
C : 0 % vs 0 %
D : 17 % vs 20 %
```

I have tried many ways around this, but I cant seem to figure a way to print the output I need.

Answer (score 1):

```
for k in dict1: 
    print("{} : {}% vs {}%".format(k, int(dict1[k]*100.0 / s), dict2[k]*20))
```

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.6+, I'd recommend

```
for k, v in dict1.items(): 
    print(f'{k} : {v * 100.0 / s}% vs {dict2[k] * 20}%')
```

Otherwise, I'd suggest

```
for k, v in dict1.items(): 
    print('{} : {}% vs {}%'.format(k, int(v * 100 / s), dict2[k] * 20))
```

This also enforces the implicit precondition of `dict2` having keys that are a weak superset of `dict1`'s keys (i.e. `dict2` has all of the keys that `dict1` has and maybe more.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution but I hope that it will work

```
tmpValueForKey1 = 1
tmpValueForKey2 = 1
for key1, value1 in dict1.items():
    pct = value1 * 100.0 / s // 1
    for key2, value2 in dict2.items():
        pct2 = value2 * 20
        if tmpValueForKey1 == tmpValueForKey2:
            print(key1, ":", int(pct), "% vs", pct2, "%")
        tmpValueForKey2 = tmpValueForKey2 + 1
    tmpValueForKey1 = tmpValueForKey1 + 1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `zip()` function to create an Iterable. Then, you can loop over the values like this:

```py
for keys in zip(dict1, dict2):

  # Get Keys
  key1 = keys[0]
  key2 = keys[1]

  # Get Values
  pct1 = dict1[key1]
  pct2 = dict2[key2]
  print(key1, ":", int(pct1), "% vs", pct2, "%")
```